# Is there a way to scroll through a website without being held up by scrolling textareas?

Tags: firefox

This is a user question, not about CSS. 
I have to scroll through longer websites a lot. If there are forms with textareas that contain longer Text (e.g. in phpMyAdmin), the scrolling process gets picked up by the textarea and the page's scrolling gets paused for a moment:

Scroll - Textarea scrolls to the end - Scroll on.

I find this very annoying. Is there a way to simply scroll through a page and NOT scroll it's elements?

I user Firefox on OSX, but I'm interested in a solution for any platform combination.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, voted to move to Super User.

Comment: Uh sorry I agree

Comment: Though annoying for textareas, I doubt this can be fixed without driving you crazy. It's a feature of scrolling in OS X to *not* have to activate the area you want to scroll: scrolling is applied to the part of the screen the mouse is hovering, *not* to the part that happens to have true focus (which is the case in Windows, unless using something like [KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/)). So, just to be sure you understand *why* this happens: ensure the mouse pointer is in a part that does not have such textareas (like the scrollbar, as per Matt's answer, or any other part of the website).

Answer (score 2):

Use your mouse to drag the browser's scroll bar, or to click the scroll arrows. Or, keep your cursor over the scroll bar while using the scroll wheel.

Comment: Thanks. Would like to vote but as it's moved to Super User, I can't.

Comment: And there is no special key I can press whilst using the scroll wheel?